# Apply CSS only on one div instead of all divs with "this" selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, this

I have 4 div containers which have all the same classes. Within the div containers I can click on "Show more" to animate another div container within more informations. In this other container, I can click on "Go back" to show the origin one.
Right now, when I click one of the 4 containers, all of them toggle at the same time.

How can I apply the animation (ease) only of the container I clicked it's `p` element?

This is my HTML code (for one div container, the rest of the containers are exact the same):

```
<div class="photo_box ">
   <div class="card-more-informations">
      <p>Show more</p>

      <div class="more-information-container">
         <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
         <h1>Go back</h1>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery code:

```
$('.card-more-informations > p').on('click', function() {
         $('.more-information-container').css({"right": "0%"})
    });

    $('.more-information-container > h1').on('click', function() {
        $('.more-information-container').css({'right': ''})
    });
```

Right now, when I click the `p` element with "Show more" all containers with class `more-information-container` opens at the same time. And when I click then "Go back" all containers close at the same time. I want that only the container opens and closes where I have clicked it's `p` respectively `h1` element.

(I didn't post `CSS`because it's I guess unecessary in order to solve my problem.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `this` will refer to the element being clicked on, so change your code to:

```
$('.card-more-informations > p').on('click', function() {
     $(this).next('.more-information-container').css({"right": "0%"})
});

$('.more-information-container > h1').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('.more-information-container').css({'right': ''})
});
```

Here we use `.next()` and `.parent()` to select the appropriate elements. We also pass in the class `'.more-information-container'` to make sure that's the only thing we can select.

```js
$('.card-more-informations > p').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next('.more-information-container').css({
    "color": "red"
  })
});

$('.more-information-container > h1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent('.more-information-container').css({
    'color': 'black'
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="photo_box ">
  <div class="card-more-informations">
    <p>Show more</p>

    <div class="more-information-container">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <h1>Go back</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="photo_box ">
  <div class="card-more-informations">
    <p>Show more</p>

    <div class="more-information-container">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <h1>Go back</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="photo_box ">
  <div class="card-more-informations">
    <p>Show more</p>

    <div class="more-information-container">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <h1>Go back</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

<sup>(In the preceding code snippet I use colors to illustrate the change)</sup>

Comment: Thanks man. It works. First I was applying it like you did here and was wondering, why it doesn't work first. Reason for that was, that my HTML was a bit different than I showed it here. 
**For those guys who may struggle with that too:** In the nice solution from above, you can see there is a `parent()` and a `next()` method. In case, you have more than one parent or next element into your html document, just try `parent().parent('class here')` to select that element you need to (depending on how many parent or next elements you have)